# Edit List of ViewModels in 1 View

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, actionresult

I am trying to pass list of view models to one view:

This is what I am trying to pass:

```
    public class CancellationsVM
    {
       public IEnumerable<CancellationFull> Cancellations { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I pass it

```
    public ActionResult CancelByDateCont1(FormCollection fm)
    {
        ICollection<CancellationFull> cancellations = repo_cancellation.CreateCancellationsWithCourses();
        CancellationsVM cancellationsVM = new CancellationsVM();
        cancellationsVM.Cancellations = cancellations;

        return View(cancellationsVM);
    }
```

then update some of the values, and then save data back:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.CancellationsVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("CancelByDateCont2", "Faculty", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>CancellationsVM</legend>
    @foreach (var cancellation in Model.Cancellations)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cancellation.CancellationMessage)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cancellation.Course)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cancellation.DateTime)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cancellation.Faculty)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cancellation.Id)
            </p>
        </div>

    }

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

and then get the changes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CancelByDateCont2(CancellationsVM fm)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So am I able to receive CancellationsVM fm, but List of Cancellations is always null.
What am I doing wrong? Is this because list Cancellation class itself also has another classes?

Answer (score 0):

@model declaration at the top of the view needs to be wrapped in an Ienumerable

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.CancellationsVM>
```

Comment: but if you will think about it.... CancellationsVM is not IEnumerable itself... it's only contains Cancellations that is IEnumerable

Comment: i normally only apply operations on an individual object, rather than on a list. If i do have to apply operations on the list, i send a separate post for each object using AJAX

Comment: that's the thing... I need to know how to update the list of view models .... hmmm